What does Vaikhanasa Agamam say about Dhruva Murti?
What does Vaikhanasa Agamam say about Dhruva Murti?
How are Bramha Bhaga, Dheva Bhaga, and Pisacha Bhaga described in the Agamam?

dhruvabera
According to vaikhanasa shastra here, dhruvabera is defined as below :

dhruvabhera means "immovable image" and it is divided into four kinds

yoga , bhoga , vira and abhicarika

It is further divided into three grades

uttama, madhyama and adhama

A survey of the special features of Vaikhanasa iconography reveals 36
varieties of icons of dhruvabera.

brahmabhaga, devabhaga and paisacabhaga
According to vaikhanasa shastra here, brahmabhaga/devabhaga/paisacabhaga are defined as below :

The total interior floor area of the garbhagriha is divided into
sixteen columns both east to west and south to north resulting in two
hundred fifty-six equal squares. The middle part containing sixteen
squares is brahma-bhaga. The area covering three rows of squares
around the same is daivika which has eighty-four squares. The next
two enclosing rows consisting of ninety-six squares around are
manushabhaga. The last enclosure adjacent to the wall consisting of
sixty squares is paisaca-bhaga.

